# Getting AccessViolationException after migrating to .NET 4.7.2 framework from 4.0

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport, unsafe

We have an integration with a third party software that involves passing XML data back and forth.  We have to use a DLL import for this process, as they don't have a .NET library or API.  Our project has been working fine, targeting the **.NET 4.0** framework, for years now.

Due to another component update, we're forced to **update** our **.NET framework**.  After doing so, this block of code that has been working for years is all of a sudden throwing

> AccessViolationException

We **rolled** our project **back** to **.NET 4.0** and it **worked again**, so that is the common change we have narrowed it down to.

This is the syntax provided for the third party integration.

Syntax (c/c++)

```
int VprtXML(tVprtConn lConnHdl, 
            void **pXmlContextPtr, 
            char *XmlBuf, 
            char *XmlResult, 
            long *pResultSize);
```

Here's the relevant pieces of code that handle this.

```
        private UInt32 connectionHandle;
        private UInt32 contextHandle = 0;
        byte[] inXMLArray;
        byte[] outXMLArray;
        char[] nulls = { '\0' };

        [DllImport("VprtEI.dll", EntryPoint = "VprtXML",ExactSpelling = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static extern int VprtXML(
             UInt32 pConnHdl,
             UInt32* pContextHdl,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] inParm,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] outParm,
             UInt32* pResultSize);

        private void InitArray(byte[] arr)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                arr[i] = 0;
            }
        }


        public bool DoCalc(String inXML, out String outXML)
        {
            int rc;
            ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
            int nullChar;

            UInt32 resultSize = (uint)(outXMLArray.GetLength(0)) - 1024;

            InitArray(inXMLArray);
            InitArray(outXMLArray);

            ascii.GetBytes(inXML).CopyTo(inXMLArray, 0);

            fixed (uint* pCtxHdl = &(this.contextHandle))
            {
                rc = VprtXML(this.connectionHandle, pCtxHdl,
                                            inXMLArray, outXMLArray,
                                            &resultSize);
            }

            outXML = ascii.GetString(outXMLArray).TrimEnd(nulls);
            nullChar = outXML.IndexOf('\0');
            if (nullChar > 0)
                outXML = outXML.Substring(0, nullChar);

            return true;
        }
```

The call to `VprtXML` is what is throwing the `AccessViolationException` now when it wasn't prior to updating our .NET framework.  Any help with figuring out what we need to fix would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you inadvertently move from x86 to x64 or vice versa in your project settings during the upgrade?

Comment: There are many reason why it could fail. First of all your DllImport declaration doesn't seem perfect. It heavily depends how C/C++ code is behaving with what you pass to it. Are all parameters in? are some out? if it's crashing in the C/C++ code, just debug it. Are you running x86 or x64? etc.

Comment: @MickyD No, didn't chagne the bitness of the application during the change. Only the .NET framework, and I can go back and downgrade back to .NET 4.0 and this code works fine again.

Comment: @SimonMourier Can't debug into the C++ code, as I don't have access to it.  Only provided with the DLLs and a very limited documentation on the function headers.

Comment: Difficult to say w/o more information. You should contact the vendor